# Uploading CSV Files To MongoDB | Reading From CSV File

Tags: mongodb, mean-stack

I am currently working on a project based on MEAN FULL STACK that requires uploading a CSV file from a personal space to MONGODB by a general user and then reading the uploaded CSV file from mongoDB 
and then displaying it to the front-end using html and css.

I am unable to figure out how to upload the CSV file on MongoDb and read certain parts from it to view it on the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#mongoimport) tool from MongoDB can help you with uploading data from CSV file to the MongoDB database. The mongoimport tool imports content from a CSV file created by mongoexport, or potentially, another third-party export tool.

```
mongoimport --db users --collection contacts --type csv --headerline --file /opt/backups/contacts.csv
```

Comment: Worked. Appreciated!